# 2x1 Piston Door (replaces top block)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've been looking all over youtube, I know how to make a 2 by 1 vertical door at this point, but for this build I'd like to have 2 iron bars be the door but when it opens for the bottom block of the door be replaced to a stone block.

I feel like ive seen this technique of replacing the blocks using pistons before but i couldn't find anything online(maybe i just don't know what to look up honestly)

I'm gonna attach some images that will better explain what i'm trying to do.
[image: Closed]
[image: Open]
[image: wiattd]

Comment: This would be an extremely complex build and I'm not 100% sure it's possible, but if it is possible it's definitely been done, so I'll poke around for a design.

Comment: Probably searching for something like "flush 1x2 glass door" could find something. Or variations of that.

Comment: Does it have to be contained entirely below the doors "ground level" or can there be parts of the mechanism on either side/top (ie: does it have to work exactly with your example or can it be modified if it is wider?

Comment: Mumbo Jumbo loves these sorts of contraptions. Try searching "hidden crafting blocks" from him. You'll see the sorts of mechanisms he uses to replace a block with another one.

Comment: There are many tutorials in which they show how to build a 1x2 flush piston door, but it takes the blocks to the side instead of underground. If that is okay with you, then the mechanism is quite simple

Answer (score 1):

You can make it using the following steps:

[image: step zero]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that it is literally impossible to make the bottom of the door (i.e. the block in front of the bottom bars) be another block than a slime block or a sticky piston. The steps are, I hope, clearly shown. I didn't connect the blocks to a redstone circuit as that is supposed to be the easy part. You can do the same for the upper bars if you want them to 'disappear' from sight too.

Answer (score 0):

Use non-sticky pistons for the block swapper, one tick to bring it down (all tick counts from the button press), then two ticks for the stone, however many ticks you want it open for the second swapper, then one or two more for the raising sticky piston. The input must be a button, otherwise the swapper pistons will stay extended and break the circuit. Hope this helps